$\mathbb{Z}_p[T]$ is not equidimensional??
Would you kindly check whether this is correct?
Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic integers.
Let $A:=\mathbb{Z}_p[T]$ be a one variable polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
Clearly, $A$  is of  Krull dimension $2$ because $(0) \subset (p) \subset (p, T)$ are prime ideals of $A$.
However, $(pT-1)$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ since $\mathbb{Z}_p[T]/(pT-1)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[1/p]=\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a field.
Namely, $A$ is not equidimensional (of dimension $2$).
This is surprising for me because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is regular local and polynomial rings usually preserve good properties.
Also, the example above shows that in the natural map $\mathbb{Z}_p \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p[T]$ the inverse images of maximal ideals are not maximal in general.
The property holds for polynomial algebras over fields.

This is not what equidimensional means. Equidimensional means all irreducible components have the same dimension. Your ring is integral, so irreducible. What you are observing is just the fact that unlike varieties, all closed points need not have the same codimension.

@Alex Youcis Thank you for the correct definition of equidimensionality.
